# Updating a dataTable using f:ajax needs button pressed twice or enter pressed twice

Tags: jsf

```
<h:form id="searchForm">
        Keyword: <p:inputText id="search"
                 value="#{employeeSearch.searchString}" />
                 <p:commandButton value="Search"
                    action="#{employeeSearch.searchByString}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@all" render="output" />
                </p:commandButton> (Enter keywords separated by spaces)

                <p:dataTable id="output" var="employee"
                    value="#{employeeSearch.employees}">
                ... etc...
```

I know that the database is being hit after the first button click, it's just the view is not being updated with Ajax

if I add `ajax="false"` to the commandButton `<p:commandButton value="Search" ajax="false"`

The datatable is updated as expected after a single click of the button or hitting enter just once but the whole page is refreshed.

here is my bean

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class EmployeeSearch {

public String searchByString() {
    this.employees = employeeRepository.searchBySingleString2(searchString);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want update only dataTable component try do something like this :

```
<p:commandButton value=" action="#{employeeSearch.searchByString}" update="output">
```

or just add in commandButton

```
<f:ajax update=":searchForm:output" />
```